# creating websockects connection on local mosquito broker

Tags: python, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am trying to publish some messages on a **local mosquito** broker, It works when I use the default tcp port 1883 but when I change the port and transport protocol to websockets it returns the following error: `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

How can I establish the connection via websockets.
the online broker `test.mosquitto.org` does work though.

My browser script for listening

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var mqtt;
        var reconnectTimeout = 2000;
        var host = "localhost";
        var port = 9000;

        function onFailure(message) {
            console.log("Connection Attempt to Host " + host + "Failed");
            setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
        }
        function onMessageArrived(msg) {
            out_msg = "Message received " + msg.payloadString + "<br>";
            out_msg = out_msg + "Message received Topic " + msg.destinationName;
            console.log(out_msg);

        }

        function onConnect() {
            mqtt.subscribe("bruv");
            console.log("Connected ");
        }
        function MQTTconnect() {
            console.log("connecting to " + host + " " + port);
            mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host, port, "");
            var options = {
                timeout: 3,
                onSuccess: onConnect,
                onFailure: onFailure,
            };
            mqtt.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived

            mqtt.connect(options); //connect
        }

    </script>
    <script>
        MQTTconnect();
    </script>
```

My broker

`mosquito` broker with default settings

Publishing messages

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
from datetime import datetime
import time

input_file = open('./data/bus1.json')
json_array = json.load(input_file)
coordinates = json_array['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']

client = mqtt.Client(transport='websockets')
client.connect('localhost', 8080, 60)

# Generate all coordinates
def generate_coordinates(coordinates):
    # new_coordinates = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(coordinates):
        data = {}
        data['busline'] = 201
        data['plate'] = 'RAB5674'
        data['time_stamp'] = str(datetime.utcnow())
        data['longitude'] = coordinates[i][0]
        data['latitude'] = coordinates[i][1]
        message = json.dumps(data)
        client.publish('busline/201', message)

        # producer.produce(message.encode('ascii'))
        time.sleep(1)

        # If buses reaches last coordinaates
        if i == len(coordinates)-1:
            coordinates = coordinates[::-1]
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1
    # return new_coordinates


generate_coordinates(coordinates)
```

the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 30, in <module>
    mqttc.connect("localhost", 8080, 60)
  File "/home/bihire/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 937, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/home/bihire/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1071, in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
  File "/home/bihire/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3522, in _create_socket_connection
    return socket.create_connection(addr, source_address=source, timeout=self._keepalive)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: mosquitto doesn't start a websocket listener by default. Edit the question to show your `mosquitto.conf` and make sure that you have 1) restarted mosquitto since editing the conf file & 2) used ps to check that mosquitto is using the config file you think it is. The mosquitto log will also tell you which listeners is has started on what ports.

Comment: Big thanks fam, I had it working by editing the mosquitto.conf file + 1 :) @hardillb